# Netflix and Ubuntu Mate

Tags: netflix, navigation

I am a new user of Ubuntu Mate and I liked it.  Well, I was a user because I couldnt play videos from Netflix so I have to return to windows. What can I do to play Netflix videos?

Comment: refer [here](http://lifehacker.com/you-can-now-watch-netflix-on-linux-with-ubuntu-and-chro-1644972250)

Answer (score 0):

Netflix is now supported natively in Chrome 37 and above, however afaik the Chromium package in the Ubuntu package manager does not support it.  Head over to the [Chrome Download Page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html) for the latest .deb installer package.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu now supports watching Netflix with Google Chrome as of version 37.

Chrome is available to users with current installations of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS and later.

Netflix subscribers  can watch now by installing [the Google Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser).

Also refer [ubuntu.com/watch-netflix-in-ubuntu-today/](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/10/10/watch-netflix-in-ubuntu-today/) and [here](http://lifehacker.com/you-can-now-watch-netflix-on-linux-with-ubuntu-and-chro-1644972250)